# Invert Button colors on hover using JavaScript & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a task where I need to implement a color inversion when I'm hovering over a button using JavaScript. Is it possible to invert a css class by using the invert Method as shown below?

I've tried to create it in js but I don't know if it's correct or not. I'm using JS since two days ^^

```js
const invertLink = document.querySelector('#submitButton');
const toggleInversion = () => document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('invertedButton');
invertLink.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleDark);
invertLink.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleDark);
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #3cb371;
  /*green*/
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #ffa500;
  /*yellow*/
  color: #f8f8f8;
  /*white*/
  padding: 12px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.invertedButton {
  filter: invert(button);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="button" id="submitButton" onclick="validateFields()"> Submit</button>
```

Comment: any reason you need js ? you can use :hover on the button class

Comment: So you don't want CSS `:hover`, but javascript?

Comment: I could also use Css. Whats the solution for this? 
I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid and simple questions. I'm new to web development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set invert value to 1 instead of button

```
.invertedButton {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

and try to use mouseenter instead mouseover because mouseover is triggered many times while mouseenter is triggered only once when cursor gets over button

```
invertLink.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleDark);
```

Solution using css only

```
.button:hover{
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That summarizes every single possibility!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution if you just want CSS:

```css
button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: what does the "#eee" on the background color? But thanks a lot for your answer! Going to try it!

Comment: Its the hex code for basically light gray. For rgb it is `rgb(238,238,238)`. It is also short for `#eeeeee`.

Comment: Its just a hex color value, you can check here https://htmlcolorcodes.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this, you only need `:hover` pseudo-class like this:

```
.button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color:black;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

If you want to invert colors always without thinking what colors are the opposite, just use:

```
.button:hover {
    filter: invert(1)
}
```

You can see how invert filter works here: [invert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert())

I think it's the best for what you need without adding workload to the project. if you need to support internet explorer, the invert filter is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Or in Javascript this will help you on your way:

```
onHover = element => element.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("background-color").replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(',').map(e=> 255 - e).join(',')})`;
```

Just for fun:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseover", (evt)=> onHover(evt.target));
window.addEventListener("mouseout", (evt)=> evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JavaScript like this:

```
 document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("submitButton").style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
 });
```